# How to improve the quality of CGImageRef taken from on-screen layer?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, calayer

With the code below, the CGContextDrawImage() painted layer has lower quality than the original displayed layer. Some lines in the image aliased.

Here is my code

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(c, YES);
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(c, YES);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(c, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:c];
    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(c);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGImageRef flipImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image, layer.bounds);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, layer.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(ctx, YES);
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx, YES);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, layer.bounds, flipImage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    LogMessage(@"drawLayer", 1, @"draw layer content");
}
```

**Update 1**

The layer painted in `drawLayer:` has different size from the screen.
I want to slice the screen into pieces then apply animation to them.

original layer :
[image]

drawed layer :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you open an image context in the first place? Draw directly onto the layers `ctx` context passed as the second method argument.

Further you need to set the `contentsScale` property of the layer to `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`.

To draw an image with the correct device scale (not needed in your example) use this:

```
void UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
   CGSize size,
   BOOL opaque,
   CGFloat scale // pass 0 to use screen scale
);
```

PS: As of right now, I really can't see what you want to accomplish with your code!

Comment: The scale of new layer is correct, I need to slice the screen into several small layers.

Comment: Well, then I already gave you the answer. Use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. Your approach still doesn't make any sense. Why do you need a separate layer to slice the screen up?

Comment: Yes, you are right! directly `[self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx]` could complete the create, crop, draw tasks, but the quality still bad, any idea ?  The reason I need several sub layers is, each sub layer will be flipped down to expose the layer below it.